# Can't get rid of the JUnit Vintage Engine

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4, junit5

I'm currently migrating my JUnit tests from version 4 to version 5.

I have followed these steps: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/08/migrating-from-junit-4-to-junit-5/
So basically, none of my classes import JUnit4 libraries anymore, like `org.junit.Test`.

However, when I try to delete the Junit Vintage Engine off the POM and run some tests, I get this error:

```
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Unsupported version of junit:junit: 4.11. Please upgrade to version 4.12 or later.
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:49)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:35)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:62)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code -2
```

It happens even with the simplest tests:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestTest {

    @Test
    public void justToShowYou(){
        System.out.println("Just to show you");
    }

}
```

Here is an extract of my POM:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>4.0.0-beta-2</selenium.version>
    <webdrivermanager.version>RELEASE</webdrivermanager.version>
    <log4j-core.version>2.13.0</log4j-core.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.2.12</postgresql.version>
    <sikulixapi.version>2.0.4</sikulixapi.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>${sikulixapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20201115</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Do you have any clue? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Show at least one of the tests that you think should be run. 2. junit-vintage IS JUnit4, so get rid of this dependency 3. Add Maven surefire plugin.

Comment: Please add some more lines of your error stacktrace. Could have different reasons. One reason could be that one of your dependencies has a dependency on junit-vintage-engine.

Comment: Are you sure you want Java 10?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I changed it to 8 but same result

Comment: @johanneslink Added some more info

Comment: You have junit-vintage-engine in your pom. If you have really deleted it, update your question with you *actual* pom!

Comment: I suggest you start with https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/main/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven.

Comment: @tgdavies sure lol POM updated

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` and see where junit vintage is coming from.

Comment: @MichaelKatt you were right for the dependency. Please post an answer so you can get all the reps :p

Comment: Added new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that one of your dependencies has a dependency on junit-vintage-engine. Then you have to exclude It from that Dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `maven-surefire-plugin` at least with version 2.22.0 which uses Junit5 by default.

```
<properties>
     <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
     ....
 <properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it and tell you if it works!

Comment: Mmh, unfortunately no, it didn't change the output